# JAVA array out put

Tags: java, arrays

Hi I'm trying to write a JSONArray wrapper in JAVA that takes String variables date1Str, date2Str, and Status and wraps it into the format below. I know this is not a json format but is it possible to pass something like this using REST Client?

```
[
   ["2014-03-20T11:23:25.000-07:00","2014-03-20T11:23:25.000-07:00","Open"],
   ["2014-03-19T22:06:01.000-07:00","2014-03-19T22:06:01.000-07:00","Open"],
   ["2014-03-19T21:05:08.000-07:00","2014-03-19T21:05:34.000-07:00","In Progress"],
   ["2014-03-19T21:04:49.000-07:00","2014-03-19T21:14:56.000-07:00","Closed"]
]
```

Comment: You should be able to take your original array containing the items and put them into another array and then hand the parent array to a JSON Serializer and it should output what you want....

Comment: If you want to serve a restful client, you need to return JSON. Check out https://jersey.java.net/ - they do what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is json, just nested arrays:

```
    String[] foo = {"2014-03-20T11:23:25.000-07:00", "2014-03-20T11:23:25.000-07:00", "Open"};
    String[] bar = {"2014-03-19T22:06:01.000-07:00", "2014-03-19T22:06:01.000-07:00", "Open"};
    String[] baz = {"2014-03-19T21:05:08.000-07:00","2014-03-19T21:05:34.000-07:00","In Progress"};
    String[] fum = {"2014-03-19T21:04:49.000-07:00","2014-03-19T21:14:56.000-07:00","Closed"};

    String[][] fnord = {foo, bar, baz, fum};

    System.out.println(new Gson().toJson(fnord));
```

gives this:

```
[["2014-03-20T11:23:25.000-07:00","2014-03-20T11:23:25.000-07:00","Open"],["2014-03-19T22:06:01.000-07:00","2014-03-19T22:06:01.000-07:00","Open"],["2014-03-19T21:05:08.000-07:00","2014-03-19T21:05:34.000-07:00","In Progress"],["2014-03-19T21:04:49.000-07:00","2014-03-19T21:14:56.000-07:00","Closed"]]
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm using simple JSONArray, and used your example and did this: obj.add(Arrays.asList(new String []{"2014-03-20T11:23:25.000-07:00","2014-03-20T11:23:25.000-07:00","Open"})); Thanks again :) -azurefrog.